# Excel Add In (C#) - How to deal with user settings?

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

What is the best way to deal with User specific settings with an Application Level Excel 2010 Add In?

In my scenario, a user loads Excel with an Add In installed, this adds a new Ribbon option which allows a Winform to load. The Winform collects a single piece of data and then must attempt to persist that for the current user.

Does Excel provide a mechanism for this? Is the approach similar to vanilla Winforms (i.e. maybe IsolatedStorage)?

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

Use the registry - that's what Excel does for writing various bits of information while it is running. The user's hive of the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) is always accessible, so there are no permissions issues, and it is fast and unintrusive.

.NET has easy access to the registry through the Registry class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx.